# Where does RCTLogInfo (from React/RCTLog) send output?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, logging

I'm developing a React Native application with some Objective C code. The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios) on implementing native modules on iOS use a logging function, `RCTLogInfo`.

This is great.. but where is the output printed? I don't see anything on the app screen, either on my physical device or the xcode simulator.

Example:

```
//  RCTLogger.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCTLogger : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

```
//  RCTLogger.m

#import "RCTLogger.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation RCTLogger

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(Logger);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(log:(NSString *)message) {
  RCTLogInfo(@"Message: %@", message);
}

@end
```

```
// App.js

import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

const Logger = NativeModules.Logger;

Logger.log("some message");
```

Answer (score 3):

`CMD + D` on your iPhone Simulator, and choose `Debug` from the menu.
If you haven't connected to your debugger, it will open up `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/`, and you will be able to see the log in Console.

Answer (score 1):

When you are debugging remotely you will be able to see it printed in the console.

To enable this, access the dev menu and select `Debug JS Remotely` from the options. Once the debugger session is active inspect your console to view the logged message.

Comment: By "debugger session" do you mean http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/? I have never gotten my apps to connect to that debugger, whether running in a simulator or while on my phone.

Comment: @grisaitis did you manage to connect the app to the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

When you log natively, it goes to the native logs directly, so you might not see it in your web reactnative debugger. Check XCodes Logs for IOS and LogCat for Android. Unless it's from a console log or js, log before it gets shown in the react-native debugger logs within your browser.